# For spring,the put method is not work in the postman

Tags: spring

I used the **postman** to test my put method in a spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{user_id}/profile",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void setProfile(@PathVariable Integer user_id, String firstName,
                            String lastName,String email, String userName,
                            String oldPassword, String password){
        User user = userMapper.findByUserId(user_id);
        System.out.println(user_id+" "+firstName+" "+lastName);
        System.out.println(user.getUser_id());
        System.out.println(oldPassword);
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());

        if(oldPassword.equals(user.getPassword())){
            user.setFirstName(firstName);
            user.setLastName(lastName);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setUserName(userName);
            user.setPassword(password);
        }
        userMapper.updateUser(user);
    }
```

but as see I try to get the firstName, it shows null, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this in your web.xml

```
        <filter>
            <filter-name>HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>HttpPutFormContentFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```